# How can I programmatically flag a user?

Tags: 7, users, flags

I am creating a new user programmatically in drupal7. At the time of user creation is there any way to flag the user automatically.
I am using flags module.

I tried in the hook_user_presave

```
function MODULE_NAME_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
$flag = flag_get_flag('name_of_the_flag');
$flag->flag('flag', $account->uid);
}
```

Comment: First, you're unflagging the user, but you asked how to flag the user.  Which is it?  And what happens with this code?

Comment: Sorry, That was a typo error, I updated it. That was not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that `$account->uid` exists? I'm not sure that a new user would have a UID inside of `hook_user_presave()`. You may want try setting the flag in `hook_user_insert()` instead. Also worth making sure that users are allowed to be flagged by your flag type.